# Laravel: Pages not loading properly

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

This might look useless question, but I'm unable to understand the problem here.
The problems are:

**1. When I load the page**, first this loads: [image]

And then, after uploading the file:
this page loads:
[image]

**2. yield('content') is not working.** Although @include is working fine.

**3. I made master.blade.php**, to load the first page of the website. Before it, I was working on the welcome page.But, then changed the work of welcome with the master blade, but when the page gets loaded, it doesn't show anything.

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('/',function() {
return view('welcome');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){
Route::get('upload',function(){
    return view('pages.upload');
});

Route::post('/upload','UploadController@upload');
});
```

**views/pages/upload:**

```
@extends('welcome')
@section('content')
<h2>Upload Files Here</h2>

{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/upload','files'=>true))!!}

    {!! Form::file('file') !!}
    {!! Form::token() !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Upload') !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
@endsection
```

**views/welcome:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
@include('partials._head')
 </head>

 <body>
         @include('partials._nav')


         <div class="container">

         @include('partials._messages')

         @yield('content')
         @include('partials._footer')

         </div>


         @include('partials._javascript')
```

**UploadController/Controllers:**

```
if($request->hasFile('file')){
        $file = $request ->file('file');
        $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $destinationPath = config('app.fileDesinationPath').'/'.$fileName;
        $uploads = Storage::put($destinationPath,file_get_contents($file- >getRealPath()));
}
    return redirect()->to('/upload');
```

When it's working fine when I used include, to include the upload page in welcome, but the result is like shown in the pictures.Also, When I tried to use the master blade, and exclude the use of the welcome page, by erasing the content of the welcome page, the blank page gets loaded. 
**What changes do I have to make to make use of master instead of the welcome page? Why are two pages getting loaded? also, why isn't yield('content') not working?**

**Also, the file which I'm uploading is not getting saved in the public/uploads folder.**

**Please can anyone help?**

Comment: At first view, both are different page. Is it?

Comment: the first image shows the view which gets loaded when I load localhost:8000. And, the second image shows the page which gets uploaded when I click upload on the first page.

Comment: You should use @stop for end section

Comment: Okay, I'll try that @kumarRakesh. And What about the output screen?

Comment: ??????????????????????????? you got your answer??

Comment: No, actually not. The problem's not solved yet. @KumarRakesh